# What is the purpose of first parameter in Javascript concat() method?

Tags: javascript, string, function, concatenation, string-concatenation

Consider the following code example demonstrating the usage of **concat()** method (Taken from [W3Schools Javascript Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_string_concat)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h2>JavaScript String Methods</h2>

    <p>The concat() method joins two or more strings:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var text1 = "Hello";
    var text2 = "World!";
    var text3 = text1.concat(" ",text2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text3;
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The output of above program is :

```
JavaScript String Methods

The concat() method joins two or more strings:

Hello World!
```

Now, if I want to concat the two words "Hello" and "World!" with a blank space added in between them I can make add a space at the end of the word "Hello " or at the beginning of the word " World!".

If above is the case then how should I do it using the concat() method?
Do I still need to provide a blank space as first parameter in concat() method?
Please explain me "What is the actual purpose of first parameter in concat method"? Also, explain me it is necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add blank space to the "Hello" but that is hard-coded. What if "Hello" is coming from ajax call for example and you want to concatenate it with blank space? This is where the first parameter is useful.

Comment: One more reason of not using `hello ` would be that you are changing the original string. It might be in your control sometime, but not always. Though you can use `+` to concat and it is ever recommended on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String.concat(str1, str2, str3, ...., strN)

is accepting N number of parameter. This means it will glue all your parameters to one single string.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.concat` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

A variadic function takes a variable number of arguments.

In this case, the parameters are of type `String`, and are concatenated in the same order they appear.

**NOTE:** For JavaScript documentation, I strongly recommend [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) to W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

concat is not a global function, it is available either in array's instance or in string's instance.

In your case, you can use following code :-

```
String.prototype.concat("Hello ","World")
```

Here you are accessing concat function directly from the string's prototype

You can also use:-`"Hello ".concat("World")` // replace strings with variable if you want  `text1.concat(text2)`

Answer (score 0):

This is useful when the second string (text2) is coming from a variable.
For example out of a database, ajaxcalls, everything where you don't control it's content, so it's much cleaner and more readable doing it this way. Also maybe you could have a loop that generates a couple of codes with a "-" as seperator, it much easier to generate them this way.

It's just a way of working you could also use more parameters in the concat function.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

please refer above link, it has expained multiple cases.

hope it will give answer.

here are multiple way you can concat sting in java-script 
https://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/multiple-ways-to-concatenate-a-string-in-javascript/